# Xamarin Image not Loading

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile-development

I am trying to display a list of images with different sizes and i want to display them with there full height and width, but the images are not loading on the screen if i didn't specified the height in the image control.

code :

```
 <Grid>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ImgList}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*">
                        <Label>Image:</Label>
                        <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding .}"></Image>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
```

note: ImgList is an observableCollection of Images name string.

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to the code below. You could check the image location and binding. I put the image in Android Resource/Drawable folder.

Xaml: The same xaml with yours.

Code behind:

```
 public ObservableCollection<string> ImgList { get; set; }
    public Page10()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ImgList = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "image.jpeg", "image.jpeg" };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but this was not helpful. still the images does not appear without specifying a height in the image control. example : <Image  HeightRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding .}"/>

Comment: I use the same code (without setting the height of the image) that the image would show. I was not able to reproduce this issue. Could you provide more details?

Comment: Thank you @Wendy Zang - MSFT . The issue was because a Nuget called Glidex.

Comment: Glad that you found the issue.@AmjadSaab

Answer (score 1):

Can you please make sure if you load images from your code project than you need to give Whole Path from root.

Can you please also check that **`Build Action`** of images.

Comment: Yes sure they are all checked. The issue is that if i didn’t add the heightReguest to the image control images wont display on the screen.